# Log the Network Usage of a Linux Process?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking

I'm looking for a way to log the network traffic of a single Linux process (on Ubuntu, but will look at other flavours too). I'm after something like `tcpdump` but for a process rather than the whole system or a network interface. Is there such a thing?

The back-story here is that I'm looking to validate that our software (which is built using a handful of libraries) is NOT "phoning home" - be that to us as the software developer, or to any other developers (perhaps the library developers). My intent here is to be able to run my process via this tool, and have it log all network requests while we exercise our application as much as we can. We can then review the network logs to make sure nothing in there is unexpected.

I've looked at `iftop`, `nethogs` and `iptraf`, and of course `tcpdump`. All are fine for what they do, but they don't operate on a single process. I'm aware that there are some options if I run my process in a container first, but it would be simpler if I could avoid needing containers to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run the application as a unique user you can use netfilter.

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 500 -j ULOG --ulog-nlgroup 1
```

Use `--ulog-cprange` if you don't want the whole packet.

You'll need to configure [ulogd](https://www.netfilter.org/projects/ulogd/index.html) to receive the logs. I won't give a complete description of ulogd configuration but note that it should use the same netlink multicast group (`--ulog-nlgroup`) as the iptables command (1 in the example above). You'll probably want to use the `ulogd_output_PCAP` output plugin.

Comment: Thanks for this idea - it looks like `-j ULOG` has been deprecated in favour of `-j NFLOG` (but still uses `ulogd`), and is generally quite fiddly and not terribly well documented (presumably it's not a very commonly required task!).

Answer (score 0):

I originally stated I didn't want to use containers, but found the `iptables`/`ulogd` [solution](https://serverfault.com/a/1121245/188676) to be quite fiddly to get it to work. Since it may not just be me doing this in future, I did eventually elect to use containers to do it.

In my case, I wanted to test a UI and an API, which use an `nginx` and `mysql` running on the host itself. Getting traffic from `nginx` to the container was pretty easy (using port mapping). Getting traffic out of the UI container into the API container is pretty easy (use standard docker networking, where the other container's port appears on `localhost`).

Getting from the API to `mysql` proved to be trickier. Docker really doesn't want to let containers talk to `localhost` on their host. It will quite easily talk to the network-facing interface though (via the `172.17.0.x` IP addresses assigned to Docker containers). Making `mysql` listen on the network interface instead of `localhost` completes the "circuit".

Once it's all working, it's easy to see all the Docker traffic by watching the Docker interface `tcpdump -ni docker0`.

It seems then, there are no quick and simple solutions to this problem, and only a couple of potential solutions.